# Possible: Program executing Qt3 and Qt4 code?

Tags: c++, python, windows, qt, boost

Maybe its a very dumb question but I hope you can give me some answers.

I have a commercial application which uses Qt3 for its GUI and an embedded Python interpreter (command line) for scripting. I want to write a custom plugin for this application which uses Qt4. The plugin is mainly a subclassed QMainWindow-class that is linked into a dll (so I am on Windows) together with a boost python wrapper. The python wrapper should be the interface between my plugin and my commercial application.

So my question: is this possible?? So is running Qt3 code independent from running Qt4 code in the same application.

First experiments resulted in application shutdown, I will try to investigate this further...

Thank you!

Edit:
My application crashed because I didn´t created a QT4 qapplication instance. So when I create the instance everything works well without the additional Qt namespace (which is suggested in the answers, so no need to recompile)! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this thread](http://labs.trolltech.com/forums/topic/414) on a Trolltech forum.
(Well actually that's about Qt3 plugins in a Qt4 app but I suspect the answer is much the same).

Update: link now a dud, but the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20090112213159/http://labs.trolltech.com/forums/topic/414) has it.

Comment: ok cool, I recompiled Qt with the namespace "QT4" and I proved that this namespace is linked into the qt dlls via a dependency walker tool. But a namespace definition like "#define QT_NAMESPACE QT4" never appeared in one of the qt header files, so QT_NAMESPACE was undefined. Do you have an answer for this behaviour?

I manually defined the namespace at the beginning of the "qglobal.h" and it seems to work so far...

Comment: You're probably operating on the bleeding edge of qt development now.  Sounds like it might be worth submitting a bug report to trolltech if they missed the namespace macro off a file.  I'd be surprised if the facility was in common use by many people at all.

Comment: I submitted a bug report and they reopened an older task for this:
http://www.qtsoftware.com/developer/task-tracker/index_html?method=entry&id=203005

Comment: @timday: Link is redirected to the forum main page -- could you edit it to point to the thread? Thanks!

Comment: @ChristianSeverin: Argh, no idea how I'd dig it up again if Trolltech have messed with their forum URLs without more sensible redirects.  Fortunately the wayback machine has the text; linked to that.

Answer (score 3):

This might be possible by namespacing Qt. From `configure --help`;

```
-qtnamespace <name>  Wraps all Qt library code in 'namespace <name> {...}'.
```

Theoretically this should prevent the symbol clashes which is likely making your current approach fail.